# Passing Data from Parent to Child AWS Step Functions: Invalid Arn: 'Resource type not valid in this context: execution'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to initiate a child step function from a parent, and am struggling with getting the execution ARN to be recognised by the child step function.

Have been following this [guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html), as well as other posts on the subject in Stack Overflow.

The parent seems to execute and is passing the Execution ARN through:

```json
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "List Accounts",
  "States": {
    "List Accounts": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:function:ListAccounts-TEST:$LATEST"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException",
            "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Process Accounts"
    },
    "Process Accounts": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.Accounts",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "Start nested execution",
        "States": {
          "Start nested execution": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:startExecution",
            "InputPath": "$",
            "Parameters": {
              "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:stateMachine:AgedCreds-Test-Child-Function",
              "Input": {
                "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
              }
            },
            "End": true,
            "ResultPath": "$.taskresult"
          }
        }
      },
      "Next": "SendSlackMessage",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "OutputPath": "$"
    },
    "SendSlackMessage": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:function:SendSlackMessage:$LATEST"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException",
            "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

This results in:

```json
{
  "Id": "006629000000",
  "Arn": "arn:aws:organizations::{MY-ACCOUNT}:account/o-v5zfxxxxxx/006629000000",
  "Email": "account-email",
  "Name": "account-name",
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "JoinedMethod": "CREATED",
  "JoinedTimestamp": "11-May-2021 (14:54:08.265000)",
  "TribeTag": "TRIBE",
  "taskresult": {
    "ExecutionArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:execution:AgedCreds-Test-Child-Function:{EXECUTION-ID-STRING}",
    "StartDate": "2023-06-22T10:01:08.504Z"
  }
}
```

The child step function starts with a 'Start Step Function Execution', and looks like this:

```json
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Step Functions StartExecution",
  "States": {
    "Step Functions StartExecution": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
      "Parameters": {
        "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:execution:ParentStateMachine-Aged-Credentials",
        "Input": {
          "StatePayload": "$$.Execution.Id",
          "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
        }
      },
      "Next": "GenerateReport"
    },
    ...
```

But am receiving the following error, despite the payload appearing with the execution ARN:

```
Invalid Arn: 'Resource type not valid in this context: execution' (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArn; Request ID: EXECUTION-ID-STRING; Proxy: null)
```

Appreciate the help!

Have played around with Task Tokens but am getting no further. The way I have set up the Parent step function appears to be the only way I've found for it to pass without errors. Anything obvious I am missing here?

My permissions are fine, as per the guidance on ensuring Events, and State policies are included in the roles/policies.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using an Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for a [Step Functions][1] Execution resource: `arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:execution:ParentStateMachine-Aged-Credentials`. The [StartExecution API Action][2] requires an ARN for a State Machine resource. Likely `arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:statemachine:ParentStateMachine-Aged-Credentials`

This is the snipped of Amazon States Language where I noticed this apparent error.

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Step Functions StartExecution",
  "States": {
    "Step Functions StartExecution": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
      "Parameters": {
        "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:execution:ParentStateMachine-Aged-Credentials",
        "Input": {
          "StatePayload": "$$.Execution.Id",
          "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
        }
      },
      "Next": "GenerateReport"
    }
...
}


  [1]: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/
  [2]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the answer by @justin-callison is entirely correct/clear...

If i understand your example correctly, there are actually 3 step functions involved in your example:

`Parent sfn (a)` calls -> `child sfn (b)` calls -> `grandchild sfn (c)`

its unclear however  which sfn the output or error message are coming from.

The main issue I see is that you're using different [*service integration **TYPES***](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-services.html) (sdk and optimized) which can be seen by looking at the format of each tasks `Resource` key.

In `Parent sfn (a)` you have the task "Start nested execution" defined with an **sdk integration**

```json
{
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:startExecution",
   ...
   "Parameters": {
     "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:stateMachine:AgedCreds-Test-Child-Function",
     "Input": {
        "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

but in `child sfn (b)` "Step Functions StartExecution" you have an [**optimized** integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html) with an invalid statemachinearn parameter:

```
# this isn't a valid arn
arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:execution:ParentStateMachine-Aged-Credentials
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```json
{
   "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
   "Parameters": {
      "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:{MY-ACCOUNT}:execution:ParentStateMachine-Aged-Credentials" , 
      "Input": {
          ...
       }
    }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responses. I managed to get around this problem by leveraging the new Distributed Mapping process in Step Functions. This allowed me to avoid hitting the 25k event threshold by spinning up sub-Step Functions with the main one, without the need of setting up a parent to child step function to break up the number of events.

For those reading in future, this can be done in the step function UI builder via the map state. Only thing that needs changing is a policy permission added along the lines of: `state:StartExcecution`.